# How do I have a message box appear when something is entered in text box and button is pressed?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to make a pop-up message box to appear when something is written in the textbox? It doesn't matter to me what the text box actually has I just want a message to appear when a button is pressed and there is text in the textbox.

The following is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub cmdReg_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO qryShowAll(Student_FirstName, Student_LastName, Parent_FirstName, Parent_LastName, AddressLine, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber) VALUES ('" & Me.txtStudentFirst & " ',' " & Me.txtStudentLast & "','" & Me.txtParentFirst & " ',' " & Me.txtParentLast & "','" & Me.txtAddress & " ',' " & Me.txtCity & "',' " & Me.txtState & "','" & Me.txtZip & "','" & Me.txtNumber & "')"

If (txtStudentFirst,txtStudentLast,txtParentFirst,txtParentLast,txtAddress ,txtCity,txtState,txtZip,txtNumber) = " "

MsgBox "The student was successfully registered.", vbOKOnly, "Student Registered!"

Else
MsgBox "Student was not registered, please complete the form.", vbOKOnly, ""

End If
```

Comment: Why are you using INSERT action? Is form bound to table? Are controls bound to fields? If yes, then data entered in controls is passed into table. And why do the INSERT before verifying data?

Comment: Yes, that INSERT looks weird.  Why not just form.dirty (or move to next record, or however you save data) after the first IF is confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use + sign for concatenating the textboxes. This will result in Null if even one is Null. This approach requires setting text fields in table to not allow empty string.

```
If  IsNull(txtStudentFirst + txtStudentLast + txtParentFirst + txtParentLast + txtAddress + txtCity + txtState + txtZip + txtNumber) Then
    MsgBox "Student was not registered, please complete the form.", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Student was successfully registered.", vbOKOnly, ""
End If
```

Alternatively, set fields as required in table and let Access nag the user to complete. Can also use ValidationRule and ValidationText properties to help ensure data is entered.

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Private Sub cmdReg_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO qryShowAll(Student_FirstName, Student_LastName, Parent_FirstName, Parent_LastName, AddressLine, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber) VALUES ('" & Me.txtStudentFirst & " ',' " & Me.txtStudentLast & "','" & Me.txtParentFirst & " ',' " & Me.txtParentLast & "','" & Me.txtAddress & " ',' " & Me.txtCity & "',' " & Me.txtState & "','" & Me.txtZip & "','" & Me.txtNumber & "')"

If (txtStudentFirst,txtStudentLast,txtParentFirst,txtParentLast,txtAddress ,txtCity,txtState,txtZip,txtNumber) = " "

MsgBox "The student was successfully registered.", vbOKOnly, "Student Registered!"

Else
MsgBox "Student was not registered, please complete the form.", vbOKOnly, ""

End If
```

ms-accessvba

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**